# Best way to process image as rest api response in vue.js

Tags: laravel, image, rest, vue.js, base64

I have Rest api written on laravel and front end on vue.js. It is dashboard for ecommerce store where you can connect to post shipment service api to upload order shipment data and get tracking number(with .png label). So after i receive tracking number label from post service api i need possibility to show it in front end from rest api response.

I have route on front end `shipments/66/tracking/label` which should show some shipment data and tracking label image

I got 2 solutions for this.

1. Send image content as base64 string and shipment data in one backend route GET `shipments/{id}/tracking/label`

Backend

```php
   $data = [
        'label' => base64_encode(Storage::cloud()->get($path)),
        'shipment' => $shipment
   ];

   return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

Frontend

```js
<img :src="`data:image/png;base64,${data.label}`"/>
```

2. Use 2 different backend routes GET `shipments/{id}` for all shipment data and another one for only image GET `shipments/{id}/tracking_label` which will return image with headers

Backend

For get all shipment data

```php
return response()->json($shipment)
```

For get shipment tracking label image

```php
return response(Storage::cloud()->get($path))->header('content-type', 'image\png')
```

Front end

```js
<img :src="`${BASEAPIURL}/shipments/{id}/tracking/label`"/>
```

Which will upload me image in browser from api route

And send another request to get all shipment data and show it on front end

I like solution #2 but if i will have 10 shipments for show tracking number label, i will have 10 api calls for get image for each of them, and also one for get array of shipments data by ids.
In solution #1 i can get only one api call for all shipments with data and base64 image for each of them.

What is best practice to send image as rest api response and show it with js front end?

Comment: Hey Roman! Is there actually a specific issue here? Something not working? Otherwise, this might be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just want to know what is best practice for show image from rest api response, both works well for me